# How to assert JavaScript Object in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

I am trying to get a text of a span tag and change it to number, then use assertion on this number
This is my `command.js` file:

```js
function num(){
  // this is the span text "Published August 27th, 2020"
  cy.get("span_text").then(function($el){
    var actualText = $el.text() 
    var split = actualText.split(" ")
    var year = split[split.length - 1];
    var x =  parseInt(year)
    return cy.wrap(x); // 2020
  })
}

Cypress.Commands.add('year', num)
```

And this is how I call it on my test file, and then using assertion:

```js
// test.js
const newProject = cy.year().then((value) => value
     console.log(value) // 2020 -> OK
);

console.log(newProject) // [Object] here is my question, why is an Object in here ??? I expect to be be a same as 2020

expect(newProject).to.be.greaterThan(2019) // expected [object Object] to be a number or a date
```

But I get this error message on Cypress log:

```
expected [object Object] to be a number or a date
```

I found out that I can't assert object instead of number. But I don't know how to assert return value of this object with another number. Can anyone help me and let me know what is wrong with my test, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet, you are assigning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to `newObject`. A promise is essentially the 'tracker' for any asynchronous commands you're executing (`year()` in this case). Unfortunately just returning the value from the `then` will not assign it to `newObject`.

There are two ways to get the value you're expecting:

1. Move your assertion into the 'then':

```
cy.year().then((value) =>
     expect(value).to.be.greaterThan(2019)
);
```

2. Use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await):

```
const assertYear = async () => {
    const newProject = await cy.year();
    expect(newProject).to.be.greaterThan(2019);
};

assertYear();
```